# how to keep track of current user logged into mysql database from java jframe?

Tags: java, mysql

Hello everyone I'm new to stack overflow and I thought I would throw my question out there and see if anyone can help me. I am currently in a database systems design class and am accessing a mysql database through java and using jframe to create a ui. The program I am creating is a basic mock dog daycare application which allows the user to log in and click on a widget calendar to get that date and either create or delete their reservation. if they are an admin user when they log in they will be able to click a date and see all the people reserved and they can search through current clients etc.. I have a user verification method that will allow the user to login if they exist in the database but once they are logged in I want another window to open that will have functions for them to use that need to keep track of their information to use. Does anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: Can you rephrase this a bit, and include some code? It's hard to tell what your question is

Comment: Conversational chit-chat is discouraged on Stack Overflow. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, and less like a casual chat room. Please present your narrowly-focused technical issue as plainly and succinctly as possible.

Comment: While I cannot discern your actual question, it is almost certainly too broad for Stack Overflow. Tips: (a) Search Stack Overflow for the various parts of your project. (b) For guidance and discussion, seek a forums site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/